# adicionar valor a uma lista dentro de um arquivo

Tags: python-3.x

Criei um arquivo dentro desse arquivo tem a `lista["hello"]` tentei adicionar um novo item a lista com o seguinte código

```
import subprocess
et = open("/root/projeto/a.py").read()
exec(et)
lisga.append("kkkk")
print(lisga)
r = subprocess.getstatusoutput("cat /root/projeto/a.py")[1]
print(r)
```

Quando eu abro o arquivo o valor continua o mesmo `hello`

Comment: estão faltando alguns conceitos de programação, arquivos e mágica pra você entender aí - vamos ver se aparece alguém que possa te explicar.

Comment: James, pelo que você colocou na pergunta você estaria tentando alterar diretamente o código fonte de um arquivo Python apenas para alterar uma lista? Isso não faz sentido em, pelo menos, 99.9% das situações e acho difícil a sua se enquadrar nos 0.1%. Poderia detalhar, com texto, o que você precisa fazer? Talvez o que está tentando fazer não seja a melhor opção - chamamos isso de problema XY, caso queira pesquisar sobre.

Answer (score 0):

Entendi que você precisa salvar o conteúdo de uma lista em um arquivo. Se for o caso segue um exemplo de uma função `salvar_lista` que recebe os parâmetros `lista` e `arquivo`.

Para testar basta chamar a função desta forma:

```
salvar_lista(lista, arquivo)
salvar_lista("teste", arquivo)
salvar_lista(8.99, arquivo)
salvar_lista(["R$",7.99], "outro_arquivo.txt")
```

A segunda função `ler_arquivo(arquivo)` imprime o conteúdo do arquivo especificado.

Segue o código completo. Para testar salve em um `novo_arquivo.py`

```
lista = ["Conteúdo da lista", 9876543210, "teste"]

arquivo = "arquivo.txt"


def salvar_lista(lista, arquivo):        
        arq = open(arquivo, 'a')
        arq.writelines(str(lista) + '\n')
        arq.close()

salvar_lista(lista, arquivo)
salvar_lista("teste", arquivo)
salvar_lista(8.99, arquivo)
salvar_lista(1234567890, arquivo)
salvar_lista(["R$",7.99], "outro_arquivo.txt")


def ler_arquivo(arquivo):
        lista=[]
        arq = open(arquivo, "r")
        for linha in arq :
                print(linha)
        arq.close()


ler_arquivo(arquivo)
```

Saída e conteúdo do `arquivo.txt`:

```
['Conteúdo da lista', 9876543210, 'teste']

teste

8.99

1234567890
```